# Using cut in bash on a file with a unique deliminter

Tags: bash, unicode, ascii, cut

**Can `cut` be used in bash with the `¬` delimiter?**

This question is an extension of the topic covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492090/least-used-delimiter-character-in-normal-text-ascii-128). One interpretation of the goal in that link is to use a delimiter that can not be found (or very rarely found) in human text. Say we choose the 'Not Sign' (`¬`) as a delimiter. My question is regarding the use of `cut` to pull specific columns of a file with said delimiter.

For example, say that we create a file with the `¬` delimiter. The file prac.txt might look like:

```
$cat prac.txt
"Billy""Car"¬"Red"¬"Garage"¬"3"
"Rob"¬"Truck"¬"Blue"¬"Street"¬"14"
```

The following process produces an error:

```
$cut -d'¬' -f1 prac.txt  
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
Try `cut --help' for more information.
```

The correct output would be:

```
"Billy"
"Rob"
```

Possibly useful info from python:

```
import unicodedata
>>>unicodedata.lookup('Not sign')
u'\xac'
```

Possibly useful character conversion [link](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/).

My guess is that the `-d` flag uses some representation of '¬' that I have not tried yet or else it only works with single ascii characters. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Another example: `cut -d $(echo -e "\\u007C\\u001C")`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In UTF-8, the "not sign" is encoded in two bytes `c2 ac`. and `cut` doesn't handle this, which is arguably a bug. See [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15961/coreutils-that-are-utf-aware) on unix.stackexchange.