# Terminal: send a do-nothing escape sequence or control character

Tags: linux, architecture, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I need my terminal to send an unused control character or escape sequence, one that has no effect at all layers: ignored by shells (bash, ...), ignored by line-editors (readline, ...), and ignored by all applications (vim, less, mutt, ...). I'll then bind this key within tmux, with a user defined key escape sequence if necessary. *What control character or escape sequence do I use?* More information below:

---

I want the Control-Shift-c key chord in tmux bound to an action which will copy the tmux selection into the X clipboard selection buffer. That and continue to have Control-Shift-c copy the terminal selection into the X clipboard selection buffer when tmux is not running. Terminal emulators generate the same output for both Control-Shift-key and Control-key inputs, see [1][2]. The first step is to change this:

```
# Enable fixterms (I think) sequences for all keys:
xterm -xrm "XTerm.vt100.modifyOtherKeys: 2" -xrm "XTerm.vt100.formatOtherKeys: 1"
```

This instructs xterm to construct an escape sequence for all keys modified by Control, Alt, or Meta. As far as I can tell nothing supports these escape sequence, whether they're formatted using the original xterm sequences or via the new fixterms [3] specifications. Even tmux supports only a subset of these sequences [4], rather than a full-blown CSI-sequence parser [5].

The simplest workaround is to have only Control-Shift-c send a fixterms sequence, as per [6]. Since this sequence isn't supported by tmux, it'll have to be manually defined via the `user-keys` option. It will also have to be bound in the root key table of tmux rather than one of the copy-mode tables; otherwise if tmux isn't in copy-mode the binding will be ignored and passed through tmux to one of the terminal applications.

```
# Configure only Control-Shift-c to send a fixterms sequence:
xterm -xrm "XTerm*vt100.translations: #override \n\
    Ctrl Shift <Key>c: string(0x1b) string ([67;6u)"

# Recognize (but don't handle) the Control-Shift-c fixterms sequence:
tmux set-option -s user-keys[0] "\e[67;6u"

# Copy the selection to the clipboard buffer only when in copy-mode. If
# there is no selection, nothing will be copied:
tmux bind-key -T root User0 if-shell -Ft= "#{pane_in_mode}"
    "send-keys -X copy-pipe 'xsel -i -b'"
```

All other applications, which don't support fixterms sequences, will receive input junk. Even worse, unknown escape sequences are likely to be misinterpreted and trigger application-specific commands. Initially I considered using `tcgetpgrp(3)`[7] to get the name of the command currently running within the terminal, much like `#{pane_current_command}` in tmux[8].

```
xterm <-> bash <-> command
```

The terminal binding for Control-Shift-c would first copy the terminal's selection to the clipboard buffer, as usual; then call my external program[9]. If the terminal command isn't currently tmux, nothing happens; otherwise the external command writes the fixterms Control-Shift-c sequence to the terminal's `pts`. When tmux receives that sequence it will overwrite the clipboard buffer with its own selection.

```
xterm -xrm "XTerm*vt100.translations: #override \n\
    Ctrl Shift <Key>c: copy-selection(PRIMARY) \n\
                       exec-formatted("~/send_fixterms_sequence_if_tmux.py")
```

This fails to handle nested terminal emulators, as when running tmux over ssh - which is very common.

```
xterm <-> bash <-> ssh <-> bash <-> tmux <-> bash <-> command
```

That's my dilemma and I'm currently considering several alternatives:

1. Have the terminal send a control character rather than an escape sequence. Control characters are always supported. I'd like there to exist a do-nothing character and was hopeful for Control-@ (NUL or ASCII 0), but that character is echoed by the shell and has a significant effect in insert mode in vim. If no such character exists, see #3. Perhaps I could appropriate an uncommon control character, but it would also have to be configured to do nothing, across all layers: xterm, bash, readline, vim, etc.
2. Have the terminal send an unused or do-nothing escape sequence rather than the Control-Shift-c fixterms sequence. The sequence would need be ignored at all layers: ignored by shells (bash, ...), ignored by line-editors (readline, ...), and ignored by all applications (vim, less, mutt, ...). See #3.
3. Modify the terminfo entry for my terminal to ensure that at least one of the above (control code, standard escape sequence, or fixterms escape sequence) is ignored at all layers, as per [10]. Then, bind this modified sequence in tmux.
4. Invoke readline to do something magical. A long-shot as this is unlikely to have any effect on alternate-mode terminal applications.

The idea is to, as before, copy the terminal's selection to the clipboard buffer. Then insert `<STRING>` as if it had been typed. When tmux receives `<STRING>` it will overwrite the clipboard buffer with its own selection. Any other application will ignore it: including and especially having nothing printed to the terminal.

```
xterm -xrm "XTerm*vt100.translations: #override \n\
    Ctrl Shift <Key>c: copy-selection(PRIMARY) string(<STRING>)
```

I'm also planning on extending this to gnome-terminal, so an example of writing the escape sequence or control character to the terminal's `pts` would be appreciated. I only use xterm as a working example - this question is definitely not xterm-specific.

---

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876639
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116630
3. http://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms/
4. https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/xterm-keys.c
5. http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libtermkey/
6. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2179779
7. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcgetpgrp.3.html
8. https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/osdep-linux.c
9. https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h2-KEY-BINDINGS
10. [Bind Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab in tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15470001)
11. https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#ESCAPE_CHARACTERS

---

*edit, new idea:* SSH provides its own terminal emulator, or at least is hooked up to a `pts` pair[11]. Does that mean it can handle incoming escape sequences, and perhaps run an external remote command, such as one using `tcgetpgrp`? Or would that be an insecurity? Rather than configuring a possibly endless series of terminal applications to ignore an escape sequence, I'd prefer to configure only SSH as I would tmux.

Comment: All `0x80`+ characters.

Comment: Those echo � irrespective of `XTerm*vt100.metaSendsEscape` and `XTerm*vt100.eightBitInput`. By the way, are those C1 control characters[1] or is the eighth bit just for encoding Meta, as in Control-Meta-key? 

[1] https://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/chapter4#S4.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41555511/8548828

Answer (score 0):

All the available sequences will potentially look like a key of some kind to the application receiving it (for example, 0 is C-@ and C-Space), there is no sequence that applications are guaranteed to ignore.

If I was you I'd just send the escape sequence for F20 or something and bind that key to do nothing in the other applications you use a lot.